# Update with NULL for a Numeric field with a textfield in a form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I want to be able to update a numeric column to different values and also be able clear values in a field (set the field to null). I am able to update the field to any number I want but whenever I delete the value and set it to nothing, it's giving me an error.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub txtPortNumber_AfterUpdate()

Dim portSQL As String

portSQL = "UPDATE Switches SET [Port Number] = " & Me.txtPortNumber & " WHERE ID = " & Me.txtID3 & ""

DoCmd.RunSQL (portSQL)

Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

How would you recommend me approaching this issue? I'm thinking that I need to write an IF-ELSE statement but I'm unsure of what to put.

txtID3 is a number and txtPortNumber is also numeric.

Comment: Well, to start with, it looks like you've got an SQL injection vulnerability there. See http://xkcd.com/327/ If you create an integer variable `Dim portNumber as Integer` you can try to parse the value of txtPortNumber to an int; if it fails, `"SET [Port Number] = NULL"`; if not, `"SET [Port Number] = " & portNumber.ToString() & "`. You would also want to sanitize the txtID3 if it's not from a dropdown.

Comment: how about `iif(Me.txtPortNumber = "","NULL",Me.txtPortNumber)` or something like that?

Comment: @astander it says that there is still a type mismatch for the Me.txtPortNumber = "" part.

Comment: @outisnihil how would I write the condition for that if else statement? (I'm relatively new to access so I'm not too sure how to code it) Would I create a new variable of type bool and just set it to true/false for each respective case?

Comment: @outisnihil actually, how exactly do I parse the value of txtPortNumber to an int? Do i use CInt(Expression)?

Comment: Ouch. Sorry, @santaaimonce, I didn't see any MSAccess tags on this. You would write `If IsNumeric(Me.txtPortNumber) Then \ myInt = Cint(myText) \ portSQL = "UPDATE Switches SET [Port Number] = " & myInt & " WHERE ID = " & Me.txtID3 & "" \ End If` [the backslashes are line changes].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I got started on this, I thought it was VB.NET and not Access. Let me know if this works:

```
Private Sub txtPortNumber_AfterUpdate()
    Dim portSQL As String
    Dim portNumber as Integer
    Dim myID as Integer 

    If IsNumeric(Me.txtID3) Then 
        myID = CInt(Me.txtID3) 

        If IsNumeric(Me.txtPortNumber) Then
            portNumber = CInt(Me.txtPortNumber) 
            portSQL = "UPDATE Switches SET [Port Number] = " & portNumber & " WHERE ID = " & myID  & ""
        Else
            portSQL = "UPDATE Switches SET [Port Number] = NULL WHERE ID = " & myID  & ""
        End If 
        DoCmd.RunSQL (portSQL)

    End If
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: hmm, I just copy and pasted your code over and tried it. It no longer has the error, but it doesn't set the value on the table to null. When I clear the field in the form and press enter, it just moves to the next text field, but doesnt update the value in the table. However, it does work when I want to change a current value to a new number. I'm prompted too asking if I want to update the field, but when I set the value to null, nothing happens.

Comment: @santaaimonce Sorry, thought what to do for the null condition would be obvious. Check edit.